# return json result along with redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am having a login method. Within this method i am checking for any invalid data being picked from repository(i.e. i am calling a more function to check invalid data). Before adding the invalid check method the login method was returning `return RedirectToAction("HomePage", "Home");` but now i am unable to figure out that how to redirect the user to another view within this login method. Below is the code that i have written -

```
    List<InvalidModel> invalidModel = new List<InvalidModel>();    
    List<object> invalidModelList = new List<object>();     
    var jsonData = new { rows = new List<object>() };   
    invalidModel = GetInvalidItems();    
    if (invalidModel.Count > 0)    
    {    
     foreach(var invld in invalidModel)
     {
         invalidModelList.Add(new
         {
           cell = new string[]
           {
             invld.InvalidItemID,
             invld.InvalidItemName,
           }
         });
     }
    }
    jsonData = new { rows = invalidModelList};
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now i am confused that how to send this json data to a view that will show all invalid items in grid?
Please help.

Comment: So you want to redirect to home page if invalidModel.Count is than or equal to 0??

Comment: i want to return to a view that will show invalid items in a grid for that user who is trying to login, if invalidModelList.count is greater than 0. let me know if there is still some ambiguity is the question.

Comment: To make it more clear, It might be good if you share the view with grid also.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
if(invalidModelList.count > 0)
   return View("view_with_grid",invalidModelList);
 else
   return RedirectToAction("HomePage", "Home");
```